# React only saves input value state on typing but not when filled by API data

Tags: jquery, reactjs

Really couldn't find out whats wrong with my code.

I've setup a form that has a addresslookup function in it. The addresslookup works with an api that gives the street and city when providing the postal code and housenumber.

So the street field and city field values are filled by the api.

The form saves all values from the input fields in the state which gets pushed to MongoDB.

For some reason it doesnt save the values the API provides. Only when I type an extra character into the given street and city fields.

I've tried a dirty solution with jQuery where it adds an extra space to the street and city when the values are filled with data. Unfortunately it really only saves the value by typing in a value only.

REACT:
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

```
    this.onChangeRegisterPostcode = this.onChangeRegisterPostcode.bind(this);
    this.onChangeRegisterHuisnummer = this.onChangeRegisterHuisnummer.bind(this);
    this.onChangeRegisterToevoeging = this.onChangeRegisterToevoeging.bind(this);
    this.onChangeRegisterStraatnaam = this.onChangeRegisterStraatnaam.bind(this);
    this.onChangeRegisterWoonplaats = this.onChangeRegisterWoonplaats.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        register_postcode: '',
        register_huisnummer: '',
        register_toevoeging: '',
        register_straatnaam: '',
        register_woonplaats: ''
    }
}
update = (e) => {
    this.props.update(e.target.name, e.target.value); 
}
onChangeRegisterPostcode(e) {
    this.setState({
        register_postcode: e.target.value
    })
    this.props.update(e.target.name, e.target.value);
}
onChangeRegisterHuisnummer(e) {
    this.setState({
        register_huisnummer: e.target.value
    })
    this.props.update(e.target.name, e.target.value);
}
onChangeRegisterToevoeging(e) {
    this.setState({
        register_toevoeging: e.target.value
    })
    this.props.update(e.target.name, e.target.value);
}
onChangeRegisterStraatnaam(e) {
    this.setState({
        register_straatnaam: e.target.value
    })
    this.props.update(e.target.name, e.target.value);
}
onChangeRegisterWoonplaats(e) {
    this.setState({
        register_woonplaats: e.target.value
    })
    this.props.update(e.target.name, e.target.value);
}

componentDidMount() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form#registerForm').keyup(async function() {
        if ($('input[name="postcode"]').val().length >= 4 && $('input[name="huisnummer"]').val().length >= 1) {
            const postcode = $('input[name="postcode"]').val();
            const huisnummer = $('input[name="huisnummer"]').val();
            $.ajax({
            url: `http://localhost:5000/subscription/addressLookup?postalcode=${postcode}&housenumber=${huisnummer}&housenumberext=`,
            type: "get", //send it through get method
            success: function(response) {
                $('input[name="straatnaam"]').val(response.street);
                $('input[name="woonplaats"]').val(response.city);
                $('input[name="straatnaam"]').attr('value', response.street);
                $('input[name="woonplaats"]').attr('value', response.city);
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                console.log(xhr)
            }
            });
        }
        });
    });
}
```

HTML:

example of an input:

name="woonplaats" value={this.state.register_woonplaats} onChange={this.onChangeRegisterWoonplaats}/>

Many thanks in advance!!

Link to screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C8Zu.jpg

Comment: just call setState instead of using JQuery to assign the value

Answer (score 0):

The whole `ready` and `keyup` thing is not the React approach. See [the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) for how to do forms.

The main issue with your field update is that this is not how you update a React-controlled input:

```
success: function(response) {
    $('input[name="straatnaam"]').val(response.street);
    $('input[name="woonplaats"]').val(response.city);
    $('input[name="straatnaam"]').attr('value', response.street);
    $('input[name="woonplaats"]').attr('value', response.city);
},
```

Instead, you use `setState` to set your component state. To use `setState` you need a reference to your component. You either do

```
var component = this;
```

prior to your `ready` callback and then:

```
success: (response) => {
    component.setState({
        register_straatnaam: response.street,
        register_woonplaats: response.city
    });
},
```

or [several other options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback).

Comment: Thanks guys! You are the best! Learned a lot from this.

Comment: I've responded with a different approach but it doesnt save the state yet. What do you think? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call setState in order to update the inputs field instead of using jquery/JS DOM API

```
componentDidMount() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form#registerForm').keyup(async function() {
        if ($('input[name="postcode"]').val().length >= 4 && $('input[name="huisnummer"]').val().length >= 1) {
            const postcode = $('input[name="postcode"]').val();
            const huisnummer = $('input[name="huisnummer"]').val();
            $.ajax({
            url: `http://localhost:5000/subscription/addressLookup?postalcode=${postcode}&housenumber=${huisnummer}&housenumberext=`,
            type: "get", //send it through get method
            success: (response)=> {
               this.setState({register_straatnaam:response.street})
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                console.log(xhr)
            }
            });
        }
        });
    });
}
```

It is not a good pracitse to use Jquery in React code [read this for info](https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/if-you-think-you-need-jquery-in-your-react-app-you-re-doing-it-wrong-77899ed7217e).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I solved it differently without jQuery but unfortunately it doesn't save the data yet.

```
onChangeRegisterHuisnummer(e) {

    if( e.target.value[e.target.value.length - 1] > 1 ) {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/subscription/addressLookup?postalcode=2592an&housenumber=494&housenumberext=`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
             this.setState({
                register_straatnaam: response.street,
                register_woonplaats: response.city
            });
            console.log(response.city);
    })
}
this.props.update(e.target.name, e.target.value);
```